# sprintf-Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I have this code.

```
    sprintf((char *)pData,"%c%02X%c%02X%
    02X",ASCII_STX,m_uSessionId,m_chSequenceChar,m_nMessageId,m_uVersion);

    NSLog("%@",pData);
```

But its `not printing` me the `contents` of pData. Tried with `%d` as format specifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.  Perhaps it is not recognizing pData as a string:

```
NSLog( @"%s", pData );
```

Comment: %@ is the format specifier for an object. You (the OP) are trying to log a C string, i.e. a char*, not an object. %s is the correct format specifier to use in that case.

Answer (score 14):

Maybe you'll use the Obj-C method?

```
NSString *pData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%02X%c%02X%02X", ASCII_STX, m_uSessionId, m_chSequenceChar, m_nMessageId, m_uVersion];
NSLog(@"%@",pData);
```